# UTF-8 to UTF-16, different results using iconv vs mbstring

Tags: php, utf-8, utf-16, iconv, mbstring

I'm getting different results in php when using iconv vs mb_convert_encoding when trying to convert UTF-8 to UTF-16.

`echo iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', 'test'); // ��test`

`echo mb_convert_encoding('test', 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8'); // test`

Notice the two � symbols at the beginning of the beginning of the iconv() output.

Any thoughts on why mb_convert_encoding isn't doing the same?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iconv` adds a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the begging of the output string. So for converting string, you probably want to use `mb_convert_encoding`. `iconv` can be more useful for files.

Comment: Thank you. If I prepend the UTF-16 BOM characters to the mb_convert_encoding() string I get the exact same output as iconv().